# Cordova android revision to low

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build a cordova app for android, but I get the following error:

```
The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.3) is too low for project 'Testing'.
Minimum required is 19.1.0
```

How do I update the revision of my android sdk?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start the android SDK Manager (you can start it with calling "android" from the command line (which should work for you because Cordova already works a bit).

There you can install a newer version of the Android SDK Build-tools, just click the checkbox and press Install package.

See screenshot here:
[SDK-manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html)